# JWT Error while running signing up method into app in Flutter application with Laravel backend

Tags: android, laravel, flutter

Im kind of new to stack so pardon my way of asking..
Actually Im running a flutter application with a Laravel backend and recently made a signup method in the application where the user clicks on the signup arrow but upon clicking I receive this error(something about a JWT)

```html
Undefined variable $jwt_token,
/flutter (19842): {message: Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac::createHash(): Argument #2 ($key) must be of type Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key, null given, called in C:\Users\ACER\Desktop\flutterappwithbackend-master\flutterappwithbackend-master\laravel\vendor\lcobucci\jwt\src\Signer\BaseSigner.php
on line 34 E/flutter (19842): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null E/flutter (19842): #0 _SignUpState._register (package:flutter_app_backend/singup_login/sing_up.dart:46:12)
E/flutter (19842):
<asynchronous suspension>
```

This is the code that has the JWT mentioned in that.This is the USerController that has the regestration and login details to be sent to the databse and requested.

```html
?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Auth;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Mail;
use App\Mail\PasswordReset;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request){
        $plainPassword=$request->password;
        $password=bcrypt($request->password);
        $request->request->add(['password' => $password]);
 
        // create the user account 
        $created=User::create($request->all());
        $request->request->add(['password' => $plainPassword]);
        // login now..
        return $this->login($request);
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        
        $input = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $jwt_token = null;
        if (!$jwt_token = JWTAuth::attempt($input)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Invalid Email or Password',
            ], 401);
        }
        // get the user 
        $user = Auth::user();
       
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'token' => $jwt_token,
            'user' => $user
        ]);
    }
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        if(!User::checkToken($request)){
            return response()->json([
             'message' => 'Token is required',
             'success' => false,
            ],422);
        }
        
        try {
            JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::parseToken($request->token));
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'User logged out successfully'
            ]);
        } catch (JWTException $exception) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Sorry, the user cannot be logged out'
            ], 500);
        }
    }

    public function getCurrentUser(Request $request){
       if(!User::checkToken($request)){
           return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Token is required'
           ],422);
       }
        
        $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
       // add isProfileUpdated....
       $isProfileUpdated=false;
        if($user->isPicUpdated==1 && $user->isEmailUpdated){
            $isProfileUpdated=true;
            
        }
        $user->isProfileUpdated=$isProfileUpdated;

        return $user;
}

   
public function update(Request $request){
    $user=$this->getCurrentUser($request);
    if(!$user){
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'User is not found'
        ]);
    }
   
    unset($data['token']);

    $updatedUser = User::where('id', $user->id)->update($data);
    $user =  User::find($user->id);

    return response()->json([
        'success' => true, 
        'message' => 'Information has been updated successfully!',
        'user' =>$user
    ]);
}



}
```

It would be grateful if this error would be solved as I've spent hours solving this but still couldn't find out the solution. Please do let me know  if u guys would like to see my code for this issue.

Comment: The method you are calling expects two values, the second of which must be a Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key, and you are either passing only one value, or something which evaluates to null as the second value.

Comment: @GilesBennett I have edited above n put my code...i know little of the JWT as i only used it for the login and registration as a template.

Comment: tried finding the  JWT and only got that from the code..cant find it anywea else